# Changing file extensions while copying into a new sub directory C++

Tags: c++, c++17

I have a directory that contains files (mostly images) and am trying to create a new sub directory named Thumbnails that will copy all images and replace the file extension from ".jpg" || ".png" to ".thumb".

So far my code will copy all the files into the new sub directory but I can't find a way to ignore all the files that are not images (it's copying every single file in the original directory) and to change the extension of the files that where copied.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>

using namespace std;
namespace fs = std::experimental::filesystem;

//Predefined Functions
void createThumbnails(string path);


int main(void)
{
    string DailyFolderPath =  ".../images";

    createThumbnails(DailyFolderPath);

    return 0;
}

void createThumbnails(string path)
{

    //Create Thumbnail Sub Directory 
    string newThumbDir = path + "/Thumbnails"; 
    fs::create_directories(newThumbDir);

    //Copy files into Thumbnail Directory
    fs::copy(path, newThumbDir);

    for (const auto & p : fs::directory_iterator(newThumbDir))
    cout << p.path().filename() << endl; 

}
```

Comment: you need to use copy_file and to specify the input path and output path. You will need to change the input file name to be the new file name

Comment: if I use copy_file it will only copy one file at a time. The directories I will be using it on always differ in number of images and names. How could I implement it in an iterative manner?

Comment: directory iterate over the input directory

Comment: @pm100 I have been trying to implement the following with no results, could you please help me out with it:                                                                                                                                                                                                    `for (const auto & p : fs::directory_iterator(newThumbDir))
  if (p.path().filename().extension() == ".jpg" || p.path().filename().extension() == ".png")
  {
   fs::copy_file(p.path().filename(), p.path().filename().replace_extension(".thumb"));
  }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your attempt proposed in comment cannot work because you are passing only filenames instead the full paths to files:

```
fs::copy_file(p.path().filename(), p.path().filename().replace_extension(".thumb"));
                       ^^^^^ your app doesn't see these files
```

You can try something like this:

```
void createThumbnails(string source)
{
    fs::path newThumbDir = source + "/Thumbnails"; 
    fs::create_directories(newThumbDir);

    for (const auto & p : fs::directory_iterator(source)) // iterate over all files in source dir
    {
      fs::path fileToCopy = p; // make copy of path to source file
      if (fileToCopy.extension() == ".png" || fileToCopy.extension() == ".jpg")
      {
        fileToCopy.replace_extension(".thumb"); // change extension
        fs::path target = newThumbDir / fileToCopy.filename(); // targetDir/name.thumb
        fs::copy_file(p,target); // pass full paths
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @rafix07 for pointing me in the right track. I managed to get it to do exactly what I was trying to do.